# cubic interpolation in java

Tags: java, math, interpolation

For a Java program I'm making I need to interpolate 4 points, to calculate the y-value of a 5th point, at given x-value.
Say I have the following points:

```
p1(0, 0)
p2(1, 2)
p3(2, 4)
p4(3, 3)
// The x-values will always be 0, 1, 2, and 3
```

Now I want to interpolate these points to find what the y-value should be for given x, say x=1.2 (this x value will always be between point 2 and point 3)

Can anyone help me to make a Java method for finding the y coordinate of this fifth point?

Comment: What interpolation method are you planning to use? What values are pre-determined? Gradients? second gradients?

Comment: Please confirm: are you wanting to fit to a cubic polynomial?

Comment: I just need the line to be smooth between the four points, I guess that is called cubic interpolation (but I might be wrong..)

Comment: This is quite a complex field which is why I need some more clarification. Do you want it to be "graphically" smooth or "mathematically" smooth?

Comment: Why does it have to be one or the either? You can fit a 3rd degree polynomial exactly (ax^3+bx^2+cx+d = 0) to 4 points...

Comment: @KevinL Indeed you can but cubics can wiggle around like the loch ness monster. Catmull-Rom is probably the way to go if you want to "keep up appearances". Or use a piecewise cubic spline method.

Comment: Actually I want to use this for an opengl project, to get a nicer terrain. This because the terrain is defined at only a few points, and I want the surface to be smooth to look real. So graphically smooth should be enough

Comment: Use Catmull-Rom then. You just *might* get a full answer, but this technique is well-written about on the internet.

Comment: @Bathsheba Catmull-Rom uniform seems to be the thing I'm looking for, if you put this in an answer I can give you the credits for giving the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Generally given two points (x0,y0) and (x1,y1), for x0 < x < x1, by interpolation,
y = y0 + (x - x0)/(x1 - x0) * (y1 - y0)

Here,
y = 2 + (x-1) * 2

Answer (score 0):

There are an infinite number of lines that can go through all four of your points.

For example, you could assume that at each point the slope is zero and then draw simple s shaped curves between them, or you could assume that the slope is calculated from the neighboring points (with some special decisions about the ends), or you could assume that the slope at the points is 2, etc.

And it doesn't stop there, you could effectively draw a curve that will encapsulate your points and any other point you could imagine while still meeting the requirement of being continuous (as you call, smooth).

I think you need to start off with a formula you wish to fit against the points, and then choose the technique you use to minimize the error of the fit.  Without you making more decisions, it is very likely that it will be very hard to give more direction.

Comment: Technically you are right, there are an infinite possible solutions, but interpolation generally gives only one solution. This because in theory you could make the slope at each point equal say 1000, but this would not look as a smooth line.

Comment: If you chose a function of sine waves to "integrate" your points, it would be both smooth, and with the right frequency, give you any slope you wanted on any point.  You start off with the characteristics of the curve (aka the formula) and then attempt a fit, or you come up with something that looks good, but is at best a piece wise formula.